# STG_E_PATHNOTFOUND Error Using RDOMail SaveAs

Tags: email, save, outlook-redemption

I am getting error STG_E_PATHNOTFOUND when I try to save certain files to Windows using RDOMail.SaveAs.

I am using the subject of the email as the filename, and, for example, this filename throws the error:-

*Viewpoint For Projects™ Transmittal Notification from Emma Hooper on Architectural model upload package (P23) -  Advance2, Architectural model upload package, P23, S1-Suitable to 'Share' for Co-ordination, #Y5B2J.msg*

All the problem filenames appeared to include ™ so I tried stripping this out but the error persists.

I don't think it is the length of the filename that is causing the problem, and I can create a file in Windows and rename it with any of the problem filenames such as the one above.  So the evidence points to a problem in RDOMail converting the text into a filename, rather than a problem with Windows.

Can anyone throw any light on this?

Any assistance will be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file name does not include characters invalid in file names, such as ":".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I had already worked that one out, and had written a routine to convert all invalid characters (that I am aware of) into '-'.